# Refresh in DeepZoom

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I'm in university in France in computer sciences and for a project, we have to understand how Deepzoom works. My problem is that when I change a picture in a Deepzoom folder, it takes a lot of time to be taken into account even if I refresh the webpage.
So my my question is: how can I do to make my modification having an immediate effect on the Deepzoom image?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser is probably caching the image tiles. It's generally better to make a new image and point your viewer at that instead.